# Prevent Android ActionBar from scrolling

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I have 5 tabs in my ActionBar and I've styled them to remove padding and reduce the text size on the tabs, but no matter I do, the tab bar will scroll just a few pixels in either direction. My tabs all fit, so I don't want them to be able to slide back and forth, even if a little bit.

How do I prevent the ActionBar tabs from being scrollable?

I'm using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/index.html) in my project so that I can have a uniform UI across different versions of Android.

As you can see below, there is plenty of space so I don't see any reason it should be able to wiggle/scroll when all of the tabs fit just fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are no secrets, it simply means there are too much tabs in your ActionBarSherlock and/or their width is too big.

here is an exemple of tab layout with an image and a text :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/tab_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="8dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tab_icon"
        android:layout_width="28dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tab_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Are you using a TabAdapter ? maybe you could post your code to see if there is something goin on ?